# Docker - start a container at random time

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have 3 vps with docker installed. I have created a docker image and I would like to know if there is a possibility to configure docker or docker-compose in such a way that these 3 containers run only once a day at random hours.

I have not found any way other than to configure the command to start the docker in a bash script, called from the Linux crontab, which waits for a while at random. Are there better better solutions?
Maybe k8s / k3s?

Comment: Docker/Docker-compose does not have a native way to schedule a container to run at random times. A cronjob would be the easiest way to do that as you suggested. If you are already using k8s, Kubernetes does natively support cronjobs. Check out https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: I think the solution you offered - a bash script called from linux crontab sounds like a easy to implement and cheap solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "randomness" is part of your application behaviour, then you should contain this logic inside one of services / containers, so this is no-brainer. You are running entire stack with `docker-compose` and it just works.

Other than that `Crontab` or other external scheduler (like kubernetes cron jobs) is the way of doing that if running those three containers on random time once a day is your requirement of using those docker services.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

Possible solutions to this problem are listed below.

**Docker**

Bash script, which is called from Linux crontab to start Docker.

**Kubernetes**

Since Docker / Docker-compose does't have its own way of scheduling a container to run at random time, CronJob might be the easiest way to do this.

More information about CronJobs is available in [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)